# How do I prevent to be redirect to the link in 'otherwise' in 'routeProvider'

Tags: angularjs

Ok this question is a bit complex to explain.

I use `ng-view`, `$routeProvider` and `$routeChangeStart` to make an authorization login/signup system.

my js code is here

```
    app.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/login', {
        title: 'Login',
        templateUrl: 'authorization/login.html',
        controller: 'authCtrl'
        })
        .when('/profile', {
        title: 'Profile',
        templateUrl: 'authorization/profile/index.html',
        controller: 'authCtrl'
        })
        .when('/myaccount', {
        title: 'MyAccount',
        templateUrl: 'authorization/profile/account/index.html',
        controller: 'authCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/login'
        });
    }
])
.run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'loginService', function ($rootScope, $location, loginService) {
    var routeLogin = ['/login', '/signup']; //pages required before login
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
        $rootScope.authenticated = false;
        loginService.get('session').then(function (results) {
            if (results.cid) {
                $rootScope.authenticated = true;
                $rootScope.cid = results.cid;
                $rootScope.personal_name = results.personal_name;
                $rootScope.personal_email = results.personal_email;
                if(routeLogin.indexOf($location.path()) != -1) {
                    $location.path('/profile');
                }
            } else {
                if (routeLogin.indexOf($location.path()) == -1) {
                    $location.path("/login");
                }
            }
        });
    });
}]);
```

After login, I want to use `<a href="#/profile/account">` or ng-href in the profile page to direct to my account page, which is the 'myaccount' in `$routeProvider`.

However, after I click the link, the script always uses the 'otherwise' option in the `$routeProvider` and redirect me back the profile page (because I have logged in, so it redirect to the login page and then redirect to the profile page).

And if I don't use otherwise, the authorization system won't work, and give me a blank page (unless if I create an .htaccess file but I am not sure if it will work or I should do that).

Could anyone tells me why is that and how to fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: There is no route defined for /profile/account, isn't it?

Comment: Did you try `$location.path('/#/profile');`  and `$location.path("/#/login");` ?

Comment: @estus I have defined '/myaccount', which is for the '/profile/account', while the 'authorization' folder is like 'partial' folder. But the problem is that I want to create a url link in html, how could i use the route?

Comment: @Yaniv Efraim Do you mean '<a href="{{$location.path('#/profile/account')}}">'? I tried it did not work

Comment: Did you try with '/' before the '#': `<a href="{{$location.path('/#/profile/account')}}">` ?

Comment: @Yaniv Efraim I tried <a href="{{$location.path('/#/profile/account')}}">,  it did not work either :-(

Comment: @JamesChen wait, you do not have route configured for this!

Comment: @Yaniv Efraim sorry isn't the app.config configure the routes? I put the '/myaccount' there which should redirect to the account page when it calls